# How load page to the webbrowser object from htmlagilitypack document - wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, load, webbrowser-control, html-agility-pack

What i want is download the webpage via htmlagilitypack, modify some values like inserting a jquery function and then loading that modified page to the c# 4.0 wpf webbrowser object. How can i do that ?

webbrowser object need to load page like a regular navigate process. I mean loading every css files image files js files.  Thank you.